# Why is node.js Buffer.allocUnsafe() 3 orders of magnitude slower than C malloc()?

Tags: c, node.js, performance, memory, allocation

C (compiled with -O6) takes 16us or 4us for allocation of 2GB of memory:

```
 ./2d
115
16
 ./2d
31
4
 cat 2d.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
  struct timeval tm0,tm1,tm2,tm3;
  unsigned short *A,*B;

  gettimeofday(&tm0, NULL); A = malloc(2); gettimeofday(&tm1, NULL);
  gettimeofday(&tm2, NULL); B = malloc(2000000000); gettimeofday(&tm3, NULL);

  printf("%ld\n", 1000000 * (tm1.tv_sec - tm0.tv_sec) + (tm1.tv_usec - tm0.tv_usec) );
  printf("%ld\n", 1000000 * (tm3.tv_sec - tm2.tv_sec) + (tm3.tv_usec - tm2.tv_usec) );
}
```

node.js does need 3ms for unsafe allocation of 2GB of memory:

```
 node
> t0=process.hrtime(); var A=new Buffer.allocUnsafe(1); t1=process.hrtime(); 
[ 11473, 848540243 ]
> t2=process.hrtime(); var B=new Buffer.allocUnsafe(2000000000); t3=process.hrtime(); 
[ 11473, 860724500 ]
> 
> ((t1[1]-t0[1])/1000000000.0+(t1[0]-t0[0]))+" "+
... ((t3[1]-t2[1])/1000000000.0+(t3[0]-t2[0]));
'0.00004601 0.003662583'
> t0=process.hrtime(); var A=new Buffer.allocUnsafe(1); t1=process.hrtime(); 
[ 11477, 352424752 ]
> t2=process.hrtime(); var B=new Buffer.allocUnsafe(2000000000); t3=process.hrtime(); 
[ 11477, 357416910 ]
> 
> ((t1[1]-t0[1])/1000000000.0+(t1[0]-t0[0]))+" "+
... ((t3[1]-t2[1])/1000000000.0+(t3[0]-t2[0]));
'0.000017987 0.002890688'
>
```

Shouldn't  Buffer.allocUnsafe()  runtime be similar to  malloc()?
https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_allocunsafe_size

Hermann.

Comment: Add code in both cases to fill the buffer with zeroes and watch what happens.

Comment: The use case I am after is O(1) time check of edge existence in a graph by using an uninitialized 2d array -- initialization would take O(N^2) runtime for N vertices. So why the difference of Buffer.allocUnsafe() and malloc() runtimes? Should do the same thing ...

Comment: One just reserves space in an accounting system. The other actually allocates and maps pages of memory.

Comment: From the nodejs.org link above: "The underlying memory for Buffer instances created in this way is not initialized. " Shouldn't that do exactly what malloc() does, just reserve space?

Comment: They mean that it's not guaranteed to be initialized, not that it's guaranteed to be uninitialized. For example, you might get a buffer that was previously used for some other purpose and still contains the data from before.

Comment: Thanks, so Buffer.allocUnsafe() can only be quick if reusing a previously allocated buffer. I did "vi /usr/local/bin/node" (vi cabn handle binary files) and searched for Buffer.allocUnsafe().

Comment: It calls `allocate(size)`, and that calls `createBuffer(size)` in case no buffer can be reused. That does basically `new Uint8Array(size)` which by [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) creates "an array of 8-bit unsigned integers. The contents are initialized to 0." And that explains linear runtime seen for `Buffer.allocUnsafe()`